# How can I use regex_replace in pyspark to reformat the date from yyyymmdd to yyyy/mm/dd and reformat time from HHmmss to HH:mm:ss

Tags: regex, date, time, pyspark

I am trying to use regex_replace to reformat a date column from yyyymmdd to yyyy/mm/dd and another column from HHmmss to HH:mm:ss. Both date and time columns are strings.

From:

```
+----------+--------+
|   date   |  time  |
+----------+--------+
| 20200326 | 122450 |
+----------+--------+
```

To:

```
+------------+----------+
|    date    |   time   |
+------------+----------+
| 2020/03/26 | 12:24:50 |
+------------+----------+
```

Here's what I've tried:

```py
datePattern = "([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})"
timePattern = "([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})"

df.withColumn("date", regexp_replace(df.date, datePattern, "$1/$2/$3"))
df.withColumn("time", regexp_replace(df.time, timePattern, "$1:$2:$3"))
```

Here's what I get:

```
+----------+--------+
|   date   |  time  |
+----------+--------+
| 20200326 | 122450 |
+----------+--------+
```

Not sure where I went wrong? Also, are there better practices than using regex_replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **`from_unixtime,unix_timestamp`** functions instead of **`regexp_replace`**!

```
df.show()
#+--------+------+
#|    date|  time|
#+--------+------+
#|20200326|122450|
#+--------+------+

df.withColumn("date",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("date"),"yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy/MM/dd")).\
withColumn("time",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("time"),"HHmmss"),"HH:mm:ss")).\
show()
#+----------+--------+
#|      date|    time|
#+----------+--------+
#|2020/03/26|12:24:50|
#+----------+--------+
```

**`From Spark-2.2+`**

We can use [**to_date(),to_timestamp() and date_format()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615307/changing-the-date-format-of-the-column-values-in-asspark-dataframe) functions for this case too!

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.withColumn("date",date_format(to_date(col("date"),"yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy/MM/dd")).\
withColumn("time",date_format(to_timestamp(col("time"),"HHmmss"),"HH:mm:ss")).\
show()
#+----------+--------+
#|      date|    time|
#+----------+--------+
#|2020/03/26|12:24:50|
#+----------+--------+
```